# Is there a way to make a cocoa pod without code, just the already compiled .framework on the repo?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I already created a .framework but i need to distribute it.
I want to use Cocoapods but i know it compiles the pod and creates its own .framework .

Is there a way to distribute my .framework without creating a new one.
Like replacing the .framework that was generated with the one already precompiled, or something along those lines?

If not, what is the best approach to share an already compiled .framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use the `vendored_frameworks` podspec attribute.

See the docs [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#vendored_frameworks).